# push notifications based off account registration

Tags: push-notification, shoutem

Is there a way to subscribe users to push notification groups based on what they filled out when they register their account on the app? If they select their position, county, etc. it would subscribe them to those push notification groups? Or atleast be able to see who is subscribed to what with Shoutem's current setup? Is this even possible to do with Shoutem extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Since Shoutem doesn't actually restrict you in any way on how you make your app when you make custom Extensions, you can just use a third party SDK like [AWS Mobile SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/targeted-push-notifications-and-campaign-management-using-amazon-pinpoint-and-react-native/).

Furthermore, Shoutem's "[Push Notification Groups](https://github.com/shoutem/extensions/tree/master/shoutem-notification-center)" extension might be an alternative. While not as robust, it still allows you to create multiple groups of users and then send notifications only to them if you so choose. It lets you subscribe users by default and it also lets users choose which groups they want to be subscribed to.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So either route, can I assume that I can't see which users are in what group(s)? The link you provided and other documentation for other SDKs I've read sounds like I can only send segmented push notifications if users meet certain criteria but I never really see the names of who gets put into what...sorry if this is a very newbie question!

Comment: I'll be up front with you, that's a "let me google that for you" type question. From what I understand, finding out personal information isn't exactly possible through apps for security and confidentiality reasons. In the end there's only so much you can find out from someone's phone as an app.